# Are vehicle modifications within scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

Clearly the title says "Maintenance and Repair".  Would it be reasonable to include in this scope 'modifications', which are technically neither 'maintaining' or 'repairing' a vehicle?

Answer (score 4):

Yes within reason. Modifications to improve the performance, mileage, handling are all on topic.

Modifications such as [putting a doughnut making machine in your car](http://onscreencars.com/tv/monster-garage/monster-garage-cop-car-doughnut-shop-1998-ford-crown-vic/) not so much

[image]

Comment: So how would you rewrite the second sentence to include the meaning behind the first and third?  "Modifications which are mechanical, or modifications to electricals which are responsible for mechanical operations, are within scope"?

Comment: The best I can come up with is "Modifications which a garage is reasonably likely to accept are within scope".