# Can modifications be included in the title for this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, scope, tags

I believe more viewers would be drawn to this site if you added modifications in the title. How is a decision like this made? Motor Vehicle Maintenance, Repair & Modifications.

[Are vehicle modifications within scope?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-vehicle-modifications-within-scope)

Comment: I've even made this featured so others can vote on it.

Comment: If you must change the name, why not keep it simple and just call it *Motor Vehicles*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my opinion, so take it as you will ...

I get what you would like to do, but really, does it add anything to the site itself? I understand in your eyes it would make the site more attractive to others. That is your opinion and you are welcome to your opinion, just as everyone else is welcome to theirs.

To me (yes, my opinion), it really doesn't help anything. To me, it is just change for change's sake. To put it in car parlance, my Dad once told me a great axiom when working on cars: *If it ain't broke, don't fix it.* That's exactly what your suggestion appears to me to be trying to do ... just fix something which isn't broke. When you do that, you could end up breaking something you're working on, or breaking something your not even intending to work on. Just not a good idea.

You say more viewers would be drawn to the site, but realistically *do we need more people drawn to the site?* What is the litmus for "more" and how many is enough? If you look at the statistics of how many visits Mech.SE gets per day, that number, as of this Meta Answer is [~74K/day](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). This makes Mech.SE the 19th overall on the list of all the Stack Exchange sites for traffic. Mind you, this doesn't come close to Stack Overflow's 9M/day, but hey, we don't get 6,900 questions/day either. We all can't be special like SO, but we're not doing so bad. Could we use more actively participating people here? ... Yah, we could. Will a name change alone do that for us? IMHO, not a chance.

Mechanics.SE obtained graduation over a year and a half ago. We worked hard to get it to graduate. We continue to work hard to keep it lively. A better way to support the site (again, this is my opinion), would be to research and answer questions, vote on other's posts, and be friendly by giving good advice to others. That will by far draw more people to the site than a simple, but possibly confusing, name change.

I'll leave it to the community to either refute my opinion and/or vote on your suggestion and give their own opinions as to whether this should happen.